# Convergence of directed family in topological space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, nets

Let $X$ and $J\neq\emptyset$ be sets s.t for every $j\in J$ $(Z_j,\tau _j)$ is a topological space. Let $\tau $ be weakest topology on $X$ s.t for every $j\in J$, $f_j : X\to Z_j$ is continous. Let $x\in X$ and $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathcal
A}$

> Show that if for every $j\in J$, $f_j(x_\alpha)\to f_j(x)$, then $x_\alpha\to x$

By convergence, we mean $x_\alpha\to x\iff \forall U_x, \exists\alpha _0 : \forall\alpha (\alpha _0\preceq\alpha\Longrightarrow x_\alpha\in U_x)$, where $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Initial thought: Assume for a contradiction, for some $U_x\in\tau $, for every $\alpha$, exists $\alpha _0$ s.t $\alpha\preceq\alpha _0$ and $x_{\alpha _0}\notin U_x$.

Due to continuity of $f_j,j\in J$ we have for every $V_{f_j(x)}\in\tau _j$ exists $\alpha _0$:
$$\forall\alpha (\alpha _0\preceq\alpha \Longrightarrow f_j(x_\alpha)\in V_{f_j(x)}) $$
Therefore $x_\alpha\in f_j^{-1}(V_{f_j(x)})\in\tau $, trouble is that potentially any preimage of $V_{f_j(x)}$ for any $j\in J$ might "miss" the fixed $U_x$ (aside from $x$ itself, of course, but isn't contained in $U_x$).  An idea
$$\bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal{V}_{f_j(x)}}f_j^{-1}(V)\overset{?}=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}_x}U $$
Where $\mathcal{U}_x$ is the collection of all $\tau$ open neighborhoods $x$ and analogous description for $\mathcal{V}_{f_j(x)}$.

It's obvious that $\subset$, but it's not so obvious that $\supset$ and it might not even be true.

What to do? I'm probably over-thinking this problem waaay out of proportion.

Comment: Can you describe a basis of neighbourhoods of $x$ in terms of the $f_j$ and neighbourhoods of $f_j(x)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer The basis of neighborhoods of $x$ is the collection $\{U\in\tau : x\in U\}$. I was thinking of something similar (?) to what you suggested, but it's essentially where I get stuck. I want to say that the same basis is $\bigcup_{j\in J}\{f_j^{-1}(V) : f_j(x)\in V\}$ i.e every open set in $X$ has an open counter part in at least one of the $Z_j-s$.

Comment: Not quite. That would give a subbasis of the neighbourhood filter, not a basis.

Comment: BTW the topology you describe is often called initial topology - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basis of $\tau$ is given by the family of sets of the form

$$U = \bigcap_{j \in J_0} f_j^{-1}(W_j),$$

where $J_0$ is a finite subset of $J$, and for every $j \in J_0$, $W_j\in \tau_j$.

Thus, for $x\in X$, a neighbourhood basis of $x$ is given by the family of sets of the form

$$U = \bigcap_{j \in J_0} f_j^{-1}(V_j),\tag{$\ast$}$$

where $J_0$ is a finite subset of $J$ and $V_j$ is a neighbourhood of $f_j(x)$ for each $j \in J_0$.

---

Let's suppose we have a net $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ in $X$ such that $f_j(x_{\alpha}) \to f_j(x)$ for every $j$. We want to show that $x_{\alpha} \to x$.

So let $U$ be an arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$. Choose a neighbourhood $U'$ of $x$ of the form $(\ast)$ such that $U' \subset U$. By assumption, $f_j(x_{\alpha}) \to f_j(x)$ for every $j\in J_0$, so there is an $\alpha_j \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\alpha_j \preceq \alpha$ implies $f_j(x_{\alpha}) \in V_j$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a directed set, there is an $\alpha_{J_0} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\alpha_j \preceq \alpha_{J_0}$ for every $j \in J_0$. But then

$$x_{\alpha} \in \bigcap_{j \in J_0} f_j^{-1}(V_j),$$

i.e. $x_{\alpha} \in U' \subset U$, for every $\alpha\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\alpha_{J_0} \preceq \alpha$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, we have $x_{\alpha} \to x$.

Comment: Haven't seen this description with finite $J_0$s :(

Comment: Have you seen any concrete description of initial topologies? Are you familiar with product topologies? Then note that we can reduce it to a single function, $F \colon X \to \prod Z_j$. The assumption is that $F(x_{\alpha}) \to F(x)$, and for a single map to a single space, the initial topology consists just of the preimages of open sets.

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of "subbasis". What doesn't seem so obvious is why a basis element of $\tau$ can be written as $\bigcap_{j\in J_0 }f_j^{-1}(V_j)$, I suppose the collection $\{f_j^{-1}(V_j) \}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$.. Yes, am familiar with  product topologies, but didn't think to utilize it here.

Comment: If you have a subbasis $\mathscr{S}$ of a topology, you get a basis by taking the family of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr{S}$. Here, $\mathscr{S} = \{ f_j^{-1}(W_j) : j \in J, W_j \in \tau_j\}$. If our finite intersection of members of $\mathscr{S}$ uses the same index $j$ several times, we can reduce that to one use of $j$, since $\bigcap_{k = 1}^n f_j^{-1}(W_{j,k}) = f_j^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcap_{k = 1}^n W_{j,k}\Bigr)$, and $\tilde{W}_j = \bigcap_{k = 1}^n W_{j,k} \in \tau_j$. Thus we have the basis of the form given first.